# Mod Rewrite problem with query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My mod rewrite rule mysteriously cuts off the periods from my query string.

For example, this is the request url:

`http://mysite/tag/2/Search+For+Articles...`

this is the query string I want:

`tag=2&clear=Search+For+Articles...`

but this is what I get

`tag=2&clear=Search+For+Articles`

Here is my mod_rewrite configuration

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/?)$ f.php?tag=$1&clear=$2 [L,QSA]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please give us the exactly apart after the `Search+For+Articles`? I also suggest you enabling `RewriteLog` and setting `RewriteLoglevel` to see what the log says.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with your Apache configuration itself... I created a simple `f.php` script on one of my Apache2 servers that simply consisted of the following:

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
</pre>
```

I then created the `.htaccess` file with the exact contents you specified in your question. Now when I hit `http://my.server.com/tag/2/Search+For+Articles...` I got a 404 error. However if I called it as `http://my.server.com/f.php?tag=2&clear=Search+For+Articles...` I got the output I expected. I then went back to my Apache config and found that the Directory listing for the path I was working in had `AllowOverride None` so I changed it to `AllowOverride All` and attempted the `/tag/...` prefixed URI and low and behold I received the following output:

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_HOST] => my.server.com
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/f.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 35393
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => tag=2&clear=Search+For+Articles...
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /tag/2/Search+For+Articles...
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => tag=2&clear=Search+For+Articles...
    [REQUEST_URI] => /tag/2/Search+For+Articles...
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /f.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /f.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1313889895
)
```

I've cleaned up some of the variables specific to my server but as you can see the QUERY_STRING is as expected.

Comment: This is good info but I still can't get it to work it seems to always drop the `...`

Comment: What is your server environment? I did this on an Ubuntu Server 11.04 with Apache 2.2.17. Aside from the AllowOverride change I didn't touch anything within the existing default Apache server config. The .htaccess was what you had put forth.